# Overfull \vbox in list of figures since MiKTeX update

Tags: table-of-contents, miktex, microtype

Since updating my MikTeX distribution, I am getting an overfull \vbox warning in the list of figures when the microtype package is loaded and the entry expands over more than a single line, as shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a rather long figure caption which extends over more than just a single line in the table of figures.}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Using pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10) and microtype 2021/10/31 v3.0, I get the following warning:

```
) (mwe.lof
Overfull \vbox (6.94444pt too high) detected at line 1
 []
```

I would appreciate any help in how to resolve this warning.

Comment: using texlive I get the overfull box in texlive 2021 but not in texlive 2020 and I don't get it in texlive 2021 if I use a copy of the microtype package from texlive 2020, so it seems to be a change in microtype.

Comment: as @DavidCarlisle says, this is a `microtype` glitch. The warning is harmless and can be ignored though (the overfull vbox is not in your output but only in a trial run). I'll fix this for the next version.

Comment: Good, thanks @DavidCarlisle and @Robert for investigating and clarifying this. I am glad the warning is harmless and will ignore it meanwhile. Thanks in advance @Robert for fixing this issue in the next `microtype` version.

Comment: This has been fixed in `microtype` version 3.0a.